# After textbox field loosing focues?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ajax/jquery. i am developing an application which takes loan number as input. When ever the textbox field loose its focus it should display the information for that particular loan by getting information from the database.

I am developing this in MVC. My view consists

```
LoanNumber = Textboxfield.
Contact Name = Textboxfield
Phone = Textboxfield.
```

below is my sample code which tells whether the loan number exists or not.

```
 $("#LoanNumber").blur(function () {
                var num = $("#LoanNumber").val();
                var status = $("#divstatus");
                $.post("/FnmaImport/CheckLoanNumber", { LoanNumber: num },
                    function (data) {
                        if (data == true) {
                            status.html("<font color=green>'<b> Loan Number " + num + "</b>' is available!</font>");
                        } else {
                            status.html("<font color=red>'<b> Loan Number " + num + "</b>' is not available!</font>");                      
                        }
                    });
            });
```

Now My question is, do we need to write a new method in controller which retrieves the information from database and make an ajax call in the IF condition is true?

Comment: Why do you think you need to make another AJAX call? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you asking if you need the method CheckLoanNumber in Controller FnmaImport? Yes you do. Also I would probably return  the loan status rather than check if data comes back.

Comment: well my question is after the loan number exists, i need to retrieve the particular information for that loan like contact name, phone number etc which were stored in the database (that means after loosing focus of the loan number text field first i check whether loan number exists and i'm done with that, but if the loan number exists i need to retrieve the information at same time .

Answer (score 1):

Just use 1 controller method like...

/FnmaImport/GetLoanNumber

Have it return the information from the database if the num exists or return false if not.

The controller could return some JSON like.

```
{
    loadNumber: ####,
    result: true|false, /* whether it exists or not */
    name: "asdfadsfadsf",
    date: "####-##-##"
}


$.post("/FnmaImport/GetLoanNumber", { LoanNumber: num },
                function (data) {
                    if (data.result == true) {
                        status.html("<font color=green>'<b> Loan Number " + num + "</b>' is available!</font>");
                        alert(data.name + " " + data.date /* etc */);
                    } else {
                        status.html("<font color=red>'<b> Loan Number " + num + "</b>' is not available!</font>");                      
                    }
                });
```

Comment: well my question is after the loan number exists, i need to retrieve the particular information for that loan like contact name, phone number etc which were stored in the database (that means after loosing focus of the loan number text field first i check whether loan number exists and i'm done with that, but if the loan number exists i need to retrieve the information at same time

Comment: @user2619542 - that's what my example is showing you, have one controller that returns whether it exists AND it's relevant information at the same time.